# Sockets python on not local host

Tags: python, sockets

Need help connecting the server and client not on the local host. I tried a lot of ways to do this, and looked for information on this topic but I could not find it anywhere. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Server:

```
import socket

serv_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0)
serv_sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8090))
serv_sock.listen(10)

while True:
    client_sock, client_addr = serv_sock.accept()
    print('Connected by', client_addr)

    while True:
        data = client_sock.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        client_sock.sendall(data)

    client_sock.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket

client_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_sock.connect(('193.109.85.11', 8090)) 
client_sock.sendall(b'Hello, world')
data = client_sock.recv(1024)
client_sock.close()
print('Received', repr(data))
```

Comment: if i have understand our question, you need to use portfowarding and connect with the public ip of our rooter. please tell me if it help you

Comment: Thank you! Everything works)

Comment: i have put the answer like that the post will be marked has answered

Answer (score 0):

to connect to a server that it's not on the local network you need to use portfowarding on the server side, portfowarding will act like this:

if he receive a socket on port 80 for exemple and you configure that each time he receive something on port 80 give it to 192.168.... he will give the connection of the outside computer to this 192.168... computer that has been configure.
Like that you can make server that can be reachable every where in the world with internet